# How to delete specific post by id ? Vuejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, vue.js

I am trying to **delete** a post depending on his **id**.

When I give a specific id like below it works. But I want it to automatically get the id of the post and delete it.

The vue file :

```
deletePost() {
    var postId = 37;
    axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/message/wall/' + postId, {
        headers: {
            authorization: localStorage.token
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            console.log('post supprimé')
        }
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

The controller :

```
exports.deletePost = (req, res, next) => {
    const postId = req.params.postId;
    var sql = 'DELETE FROM wall WHERE id =' + postId;

    mysqlConnection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(200).json(result);
        }
    })
}
```

The routes :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const messageCtrl = require('../controllers/message');

router.get('/wall', messageCtrl.getAllTheWall);
router.post('/wall', messageCtrl.newPost);
router.delete('/wall/:postId', messageCtrl.deletePost);


module.exports = router;
```

Template:

```
<div id="wall" v-for="wallpost in wallPosts" :key="wallpost.id">
   <div class="username">Posté par : <a href="/#/profil">{{ wallpost.userPseudo }}</a></div>
   <div id="deletePost">               <button id="delete-acnt" v-if="isAdmin" v-on:click="deletePost()">Supprimer</button>             </div>
   <div class="postTitle" v-html="decodeURI(wallpost.title)"></div>
   <div class="content" v-html="decodeURI(wallpost.content)"></div>
   <div class="image" v-if="wallpost.urlImage"><img :src="wallpost.urlImage"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the template where you call the method?

Comment: Not related to your question but, don't forget to prevent SQL injection attacks in the controller code line 3, for more information look into this article [https://www.veracode.com/blog/secure-development/how-prevent-sql-injection-nodejs](https://www.veracode.com/blog/secure-development/how-prevent-sql-injection-nodejs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the id from your template when `deletePost` is called

**Template** (I assume your template may look like this)

```
<div v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="index">
  <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
  <button @click="deletePost(post.id)">Delete Post</button>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
deletePost (postId) {
  axios.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/message/wall/'+postId , {
        headers: {
          authorization: localStorage.token
        }
      })

  // ...
```